# Asp.Net Core DefaultAuthorizationService runs twice for JWT tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

I tried to create an `AuthenticationScheme` for JWT tokens coming in.

For my controller, I have an `[Authorize(Policy=Owner)]` attribute.

It works, but I noticed in my debug log that this was happening:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Information:
>   Successfully validated the token.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Information:
>   AuthenticationScheme: TrustyBearer was successfully authenticated.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information:
>   Authorization was successful for user:
>   af078cae-123b-4fa6-aacb-525dc5a4d5cb.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information:
>   Authorization was successful for user:
>   af078cae-123b-4fa6-aacb-525dc5a4d5cb.

It looks like the JWT middleware is validating the token, then it's validating it again via the scheme name.  Twice, or two different things?

But then I get two more identical `Authorization was successful for user...` messages.

This happens even if I take the policy name attribute off and just use `[Authorize]`.

I checked and I don't think I've done anything twice.

Is this normal?

TIA

Comment: Fat chance but did you figure this out? I've the same problem.

Comment: Forgot I even posted this.  I don't know what's happening now.  I quit checking when Core was getting updated every other day (which I'm not upset about) and I figured I'd get an answer here or it would go away.  If I can remember, I'll check it again...

Comment: Facing the same issue, except with Api-Key authentication.  Possibly related to double log sinks.  Found a similar thread here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2756